# Why does my blue dot (user location) in MapKit move?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I have several questions regarding the blue dot (user location) indicator when using MapKit.

1) Blue dot is not placed in the correct location.  It's not just slightly off, but in a different state.  How do I get it to display in my current location?  In a different app, I've seen the dot much  closer to my current location but off by couple miles.

2) When I launch my app in the simulator, the blue dot (user location) indicator on the map view moves!     This is best seen when the map is zoomed in.  When the display is at street level, you can see the blue  dot zipping across the map.  Why is this happening?  How can I get the dot to stay in one place?

3) I had previously seen that you can change your default location in Xcode.  I don't remember how this  is done.  Can someone please advise where this is done?

Here's the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

Here's the implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}
```

It doesn't get any simpler than that, and yet I'm having strange problems.  Here's my configuration:

- Xcode 4.2.1
- iOS 5
- Mac 10.7 Lion

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In simulator current location will be set to none by default.If you want to focus on one location go scheme -> edit scheme -> option -> set location